# Setting background color tk.Entry when in focus

Tags: python, tkinter

New to Python / tkinter

Looking for a way if possible to set background colour of a tkinter `Entry` and `Combobox` widgets when they have focus.  Have done some digging and did find a styling option where you configure the widget with the focus event and tie background colour and another where you use an import module but neither worked for me.

Environment is Debian Linux and Python 3.9

Thanks in Advance !

`widget.configure('focus', '#colour_hex')` doesn't work.

An import module for styling but found out it would only work for Windows not Linux.

Comment: You can bind the `<FocusIn>` and `<FocusOut>` events and set the background color of the widget inside the event callbacks. Note that style should be used for `ttk` widgets.

Comment: Please provide a complete [mcve] that shows how you created the widget and how you did the bind.

Comment: Works like a charm ...  the bind to the above events works perfectly for T Entry and working on applying the same to combo boxes but property settings are a bit different.  Thank you very much for the input !!!